# Exit Animations problem in Route Transitions with framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I have been trying to animate route transitions using framer-motion but can't wrap my head around the exit animations. Entry animations work as they should.

I want the component to slide in from the left and slide to the right when route changes.

I have

- wrapped the Switch component using AnimatedPresence from framer-motion and used a location object and taken its pathname as its key.

Wrapped all of this using BrowserRouter

Ensured I have used motion component from framer-motion at the root element of each of my functional components

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wood-03pi2?file=/src/AnimateTrans.jsx)

App.js

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AnimateTrans loc={location} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

AnimateTrans.jsx

```
export default function (props) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <Switch location={props.loc} key={props.loc.pathname}>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <First />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/sec">
          <Second />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

First.jsx

```
    const transition = {
    duration: 1,
    type: "spring"
  };

  const transVariants = {
    init: { scale: 0.3, opacity: 1, x: -400, transition: { transition } },
    anim: { scale: 1, opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { transition } },
    exit: { scale: 0.4, opacity: 0, x: 400, transition: { transition } }
  };
  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={transVariants}
      initial="init"
      animate="anim"
      exit="exit"
      className="container"
    >
      <div className="content">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1a79XgKvvi2VyAu54LI21MbKrfSlZTL9iPA&usqp=CAU" />
      </div>
      <div className="oth"></div>
      <a href="/sec">d</a>
    </motion.div>
  );
```

Second.jsx

```
const transition = {
    duration: 1,
    type: "spring"
  };

  const transVariants = {
    initial: { scale: 0.3, opacity: 1, x: -400, transition: { transition } },
    animate: { scale: 1, opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { transition } },
    exit1: { scale: 0.4, opacity: 0, x: 400, transition: { transition } }
  };
  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={transVariants}
      initial="initial"
      animate="animate"
      exit="exit1"
      className="container"
    >
      <div className="content">
        <img src="https://fashioneditorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/i-D-Japan-Chanel-Haute-Couture-With-Nana-Komatsu-Angelo-Pennetta-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div className="oth"></div>
      <a href="/">d</a>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Is my location object at fault here? Should I change the key or structure App.js differently?

Comment: location has key property. Did you try to ```key={props.loc.key}```  instead of pathname?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, results are the same.

Comment: By the way I'm trying to solve because it seemed really weird to me, but your transitions are wrong. You are putting an object inside of an object, you can just assign the transition directly. ```transition:transition``` or you can use shorthand syntax ```{transition}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `<a>` tag to route, you need to use `Link` from `react-router-dom`. Then It's gonna work.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving this headache! I'll be more careful here onwards reading the docs. Much appreciated!